# Atomic compare-and-swap for a location in a shared memory segment

Tags: windows, shared-memory, atomic, compare-and-swap

I'd like to understand if there are any hidden issues with using [InterlockedCompareExchange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change a memory in a segment created with [CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and shared between multiple processes.

In other words, can the processes rely on the CAS semantics to operate with the memory block they share? I assume they can, just want to confirm that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAS operations will work perfectly well with that memory. The file mapping API and the virtual memory system do all the hard work of mapping the memory into multiple processes. By the time you get your hands on the memory, you can't tell it apart from any other piece of memory.

Comment: David, is this an "intelligent guess" or have you written any code that actually relies on this? In theory this should work just fine, but what I am looking for is to confirm that there aren't any known quirks in Windows memory manager relating to this.

Comment: It's just memory at the end of the day. It's really no different from memory mapped in using VirtualAlloc.